# LNK1104 cannot open file 'boost_regex.lib'

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2019, linker-errors, boost-regex

I'm currently trying to install a simulation package using Visual Studios 19. When I try to build the solution, I get the error message

Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'boost_regex.lib'

I am very new to C++ and installing programs from source codes so maybe this is a easy fix but I just simply don't see it.

I am using Boost v1.59 and I followed the installation guide [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#errors-and-warnings). I used the directions given by "5.1   Simplified Build From Source" from that guide.

I know I am probably not providing enough information on the problem, but I just simply don't know enough to know exactly what information to provide. Maybe one of you fine people can ask me a few questions and I'll try to provide answers to the best of my ability. Thanks for helping!

Edit, I have added "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib\" to my Additional Library Directories under Linker

Comment: I expect `boost_regex.lib` does not exist in that folder. I expect the naming to be different.

Comment: You are correct. I just noticed that under the directory C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib\ there are two flies that contains the word regex. libboost_regex-vc140-mt-1_59.lib and libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib. I tried changing the name in my Linker setting under Input - > Additional Dependencies, but I still get the error cannot open file 'boost_regex.lib'

Answer (score 0):

Whoever created the VS solution has set things up to expect non-mangled library names, if you build boost with

./b2 --with-regex --layout=sytem release

Then you will get binaries with the name that your project is expecting.  Please note however that this is somewhat dangerous - it's very easy to end up linking incompatible binaries this way with either inscrutable linker errors, or strange runtime failures.  Pay close attention to any linker warnings you may get!